# Primitive permutation group

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

Consider the following result (Lemma 4.4.4 from "Topics in Galois Theory" byJean-Pierre Serre, Course at Harvard University, Fall 1988).

Lemma:
Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ which is
generated by cycles of prime orders. Then:

1. $G$ is primitive.
2. If $G$ contains a transposition, then $G = S_n.$
3. If $G$ contains a $3$-cycle, then $G = A_n$ or $S_n.$

---

Does it mean

1. "generated by cycles of prime order"?
   Iimplies the inertia group at any ramified prime is of prime order?
   Kindly help.

Comment: I don't think you've stated all your hypotheses. If $G$ contains the transposition $(1\ 2)$ and the $3$-cycle $(1\ 2\ 3)$, it needn't be all of $S_5$.

Comment: Your "We also know..." assertion does not make much sense. If $G$ is generated by cycles of odd prime order, then it is contained in  $A_n$, so it cannot contain a transposition.

Comment: @DerekHolt Well, transpositions are cycles of prime order.

Comment: @SeanEberhard True, and in that case the assertion reads "if $G$ is generated by transpositions and contains a transpositions, then it is equal to $S_n$", which is still false for $n>2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I read it as "If $G$ is generated by a set $S$ whose elements are all cycles of prime order, and at least one of which is a transposition, then $G = S_n$". Still plainly false; I suspect the word "transitive" was forgotten. But this is just guesswork

Comment: I am still confused by this question. If you are assuming that $G$ is primitive, then the answer to your question is yes, but he "well known" fact in the first sentence of your post. So I am still unsure what you are asking.

Comment: @DerekHolt,  I'm very much sorry for not stating it properly, Now I have modified the question. Thank you once again.

Comment: But you haven't modified the question. You have a primitive group containing a transposition, so it is equal to $S_n$ by the result of Jordan that you stated in the first sentence.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this question links to the original (answered) question. Although I can see that this is an improved question, it makes the given answer redundant, which is bad. Two other comments: The words "inertia group" and "ramified prime" should be defined; and the question doesn't really make sense - do you mean "Does "generated by cycles of prime order" imply that the inertia group at any ramified prime is of prime order?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are assuming $G$ is transitive. Otherwise there are obvious counterexamples, as indicated in the comments.

There are also transitive counterexamples. For example, the maximal imprimitive group $G = S_3 \wr S_3 = S_3^3 \rtimes S_3 \le S_9$ is generated by a transposition and a $9$-cycle.